# How to limit the amount of users on a Rails 4 account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise and devise invitable with Rails 4.

I know I can limit the amount of invited users in devise.rb by changing the    *config.invitation_limit*. However, I want all the users to be able to invite new users, so the invitation limit only sets a limit for a particular user, not for the whole account.

I would like to restrict the amount of users on the account to maximum 15. How could I do that and display a message to the users, e.g:

```
    if User.count > 15
        flash.now[:error] = "user limit reached"
    else
        'there are <%= User.count %> users on this account'
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make validation at User model.
So, each user should belong to its referrer, like

```
class User < AR::Base
  REFERRALS_LIMIT = 15

  belongs_to :referrer, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :referrals, foreign_key: 'referrer_id', class_name: 'User'

  validate :invites_limit_not_gained

  private

  def invites_limit_not_gained
    if referrer.referrals.count >= REFERRALS_LIMIT
      errors.add(:referrer_id, 'Gained limit of referrals')
      false
    end
  end
end
```

And during registration you should pass referrer_id to model